# MS terminal services client for windows 7

Tags: windows, remote-access, windows-7-x64, remote-desktop

I need to access a system using ms terminal services client. i m confuse about those thing

1-MS terminal services client is already install in windows 7 if yes then from where i can   found it ?

2-Do we need to install it in window 7 ?

3-IS Remote Application and Desktop Connections in control panel is also known as MS terminal services client for windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal Services was the old name for Remote Desktop Services.  **Remote Desktop Connection** is the name of client software in Windows 7.